# module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute '_w_long'

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install django-adim-tools using pip, but this is what happens:

```
C:\Users\hugo.villalobos>pip install django-admin-tools
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    _w_long = _bootstrap._w_long
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute '_w_long'
```

I have no idea how to proceed to solve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my case, I have multiple Python (3.7, 3.6, 3.4) installed in my PC. The environment var $PATH and $PYTHONPATH is pointing to different version's. After resetting these 2 environment vars correctly everything runs correctly then.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What did you reset your paths to?

Comment: Yes! That solved it for me. Flaw in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: In my case, I didn't have an environment variable for PYTHONPATH set at all. Seems that you need both. I added these values to **both** PATH and PYTHONPATH: C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python310;

Comment: I have the same error but my $PATH and $PYTHONPATH are pointing to the same version this error happends to me while installing  omnetpp 6.0 using mingw.

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue running the command:

```
pipenv install --python 3.8
```

solved by removing python3.8 from environment variable $PATH, and keeping only 3.7 as default python:

```
C:\Users\MB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\MB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
```